# SQL get all raw base GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with 3 columns: id, frame and size.

I want to write query that get the id of the max size per frame.

I tried:

```
SELECT frame, MAX(size) FROM table1 GROUP BY frame
```

I get:

```
    frame    |    size
      0      |     9.5
      1      |    10.6
```

but how can I get the id also with the result?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

A method that works well in most databases is:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.size = (select max(tt2.size) from table1 tt1 where tt1.frame = t1.frame);
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `table1(frame, size)`.

Another common method is use to `row_number()` or `rank()`:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by frame order by size desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! What is tt2 in the first method ?

Comment: @galleshem . . . It is a table alias, generally very handy, needed in a case like this when a query refers to two copies of the same table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```py
SELECT 
    id, 
    frame, 
    size 
from table1
WHERE (frame, size) IN (
    SELECT
        frame, 
        MAX(size) as size 
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY frame
    )
```